# Does abstract Class enforce Implementing all abstract methods on the first level of inheritance,definitely?

Tags: java, c#, oop

If we have an abstract class called

```
public abstract  class Person {

public  abstract void Speak();

     }
```

is it necessary to implement the abstract method  if we try to inherit this class in EnglishPerson Class ? Why?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Comment: @abhiarora  no, I just tried to extend that class and it does  not compile ,the question is why this should happen. to know more details from the persons who have knowledge like you , thanks

Comment: @Servy I got a compilation error ..

Comment: Yes greate, then I posted the question to discuss why .May it wasn't  very accurate but here we go, and we should still try .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does abstract Class enforce Implementing all abstract methods on the
>   first level of inheritance,definitely?

Not necessarily. If the first level of inheritance is an abstract class, it is not enforced to implement all abstract methods from its hierarchy.

Base class (abstract):

```
public abstract class Person {
    public abstract void speak();   
 }
```

Child class (abstract):

```
public abstract class EnglishPerson extends Person {         
}
```

Child of the Child class (first concrete class):

```
public class ConcreteEnglishPerson extends EnglishPerson {
    public void speak(){
      // your impl
     }
}
```

As you see, the `ConcreteEnglishPerson` class is concrete. So, now, you have not the choice : you cannot have any abstract methods from the hierarchy that is not implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the original question has changed since I posted my answer, so I'll update my answer to match it..

An abstract class ONLY requires implementation of all members if the inheriting class is NOT abstract.  If the inheriting class IS abstract, you do not have to implement the parent classes methods.

Comment: The Original posting changed a bit, which rendered my answer incorrect.  I have changed my answer to match the newly updated question.  Could whoever gave me negative points please reverse it..?